# Shiny DT - Select row after selected row by using a button

Tags: r, shiny, dt

So far, I select a row of a datatable containing the name of documents and get information from a database regarding the selected document. The overview of this information is in another tab. Now, I like to have a button "Next" to select the row after the selected, to show the information of the next document. I cannot use the rownumber+1 because my datatable is ordered. Is there a way to get the row after my selected row by using a button?

**UPDATE:**

```
library(DT)
# ui
ui <- tagList(
  ui <- basicPage(
    h2("My Table"),
    DT::dataTableOutput("DT_show_docs"),
    textOutput("printScore"),
    actionButton("next_doc", "Next Document")
  )
)

# Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  doc_overview <- reactive({
    df <- data.frame(Doc_ID = seq(1,100), Filename = paste0("File_",seq(1,100)), Score = sample(1:10,100,replace=TRUE), Approved = rep(c("No", "Yes"), times = c(95,5)), Date = rep(seq(as.Date("2018/01/01"), as.Date("2018/1/10"), "days"), length.out=100))
    return(df)
  })

  output$DT_show_docs <- renderDataTable({

    DT::datatable(doc_overview(), 
                  options = list(
                    searching       = FALSE,
                    order           = list(list(3, 'desc'))),
                  selection = "single")

  })

  output$printScore <- renderText({
    row <- input$DT_show_docs_rows_selected
    text <- doc_overview()[row, "Filename"]
  })

  observeEvent(input$next_doc, {
   # Function to select next row/document from datatable. When the button is clicked,
   # and the first row is selected at this moment, I want to select/print the second 
   # row and so on.
  })
}

# app
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I can help you but I'll need an absolutely minimal yet completely reproducible app code from you. Please update your question and I'll answer.

Comment: I have added a minimal and completely app code. Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a feeling (could be wrong) that this might be a case of [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) trap i.e. you are asking for help with your *attempt* at solving a problem rather than with the underlying problem itself. If this is the case, you are better off asking another question explaining your core requirement which might yield a simpler overall solution. Although my solution is pretty straightforward the whole thing just feels like an unnecessary complication.

Anyways, here's one way to do this. You can get the current order of rows on the datatable using `input$tableId_rows_all` which gives the indices of rows on all pages (after the table is filtered by the search strings). `output$test` shows this order in real-time. Now you just need to cycle through this order every time user hits `next_doc` action button.

This solution will work even if you reorder your rows or manually change selected row.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- tagList(
  ui <- basicPage(
    h2("My Table"),
    DT::dataTableOutput("DT_show_docs"),
    textOutput("printScore"),
    actionButton("next_doc", "Next Document"),
    verbatimTextOutput("test")
  )
)

# Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  doc_overview <- reactive({
    df <- data.frame(Doc_ID = seq(1,12), 
                     Filename = paste0("File_",seq(1,12)), 
                     Score = sample(1:10,12,replace=TRUE), 
                     Approved = rep(c("No", "Yes"), times = c(5,7)), 
                     Date = rep(seq(as.Date("2018/01/01"), as.Date("2018/1/10"), "days"), length.out=12))
    return(df)
  })

  output$DT_show_docs <- renderDataTable({

    DT::datatable(doc_overview(), 
                  options = list(
                    searching       = FALSE,
                    order           = list(list(3, 'desc'))),
                  selection = "single")

  })

  row_index <- reactiveValues(index = 1)

  observe({ # reset row_index when you manually select any row
    row_index$index <- which(input$DT_show_docs_rows_selected == input$DT_show_docs_rows_all)
  })

  DT_show_docs_proxy <- dataTableProxy("DT_show_docs")

  output$printScore <- renderText({
    row <- input$DT_show_docs_rows_selected
    text <- doc_overview()[row, "Filename"]
  })

  observeEvent(input$next_doc, {
   # Function to select next row/document from datatable. When the button is clicked,
   # and the first row is selected at this moment, I want to select/print the second 
   # row and so on.
    req(input$DT_show_docs_rows_selected) # must select some row before using next_doc button
    row_order <- input$DT_show_docs_rows_all # gives current order of rows
    row_index$index <- isolate(row_index$index) + 1 # cycles throw the order one by one when you click next_button
    selectRows(DT_show_docs_proxy, selected = row_order[row_index$index]) # selects the row of current index
  })

  output$test <- renderPrint({
    input$DT_show_docs_rows_all # shows the order of rows in real time
  })
}

# app
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!!
Maybe it's because my English is limited, but I think it's not a XY problem trap. I have a table with a list of documents. I want to select a document from this table to see information about this document and then I want to click the next button to get the next document from the table (ordered by a certain field). But I think it's the same problem as in my original question.

Comment: Your English is fine! :). Is the table always sorted descending on Score or can the user sort it any way they want? If always sorted descending on Score, there's a much simpler way to achieve your requirement.

Comment: I haven't decided that yet. Maybe I want to keep the flexibility.
What would be the solution if I always keep the table sorted descending on Score?

Comment: In that case just presort your data in `doc_overview` reactive and simply use `rownumber+1` logic when user hits `next_doc` button.

Comment: Okay, perfect! Thank you.

Comment: Wow, nice solution and very clean way of putting everything together. Thank you !